# "select count(id) from table" takes up to 30 minutes to calculate in SQL Azure

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, sqlperformance

I have a database in SQL Azure which is not taking between 15 and 30 minutes to do a simple:

```
select count(id) from mytable
```

The database is about 3.3GB and the count is returning approx 2,000,000 but I have tried it locally and it takes less than 5 seconds!

I have also run a:

```
ALTER INDEX ALL ON mytable REBUILD
```

On all the tables in the database.

Would appreciate if anybody could point me to some things to try to diagnose/fix this.

**(Please skip to UPDATE 3 below as I now think this is the issue but I still do not understand it).**

UPDATE 1:
It appears to take 99% of the time in a clustered index scan as image below shows. I have

[image]

UPDATE 2: And this is what the statistics messages come back as when I do:

```
SET STATISTICS IO ON
SET STATISTICS TIME ON
select count(id) from TABLE
```

Statistics:

```
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 317037 ms.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.

(1 row(s) affected)
Table 'TABLE'. Scan count 1, logical reads 279492, physical reads 8220, read-ahead reads 256018, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

(1 row(s) affected)

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 297 ms,  elapsed time = 438004 ms.
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.
```

UPDATE 3: OK - I have another theory now. The Azure portal is suggesting each time I do test this simply select query it is maxing out my DTU percentage to nearly 100%. I am using a Standard Azure SQL instance with performance level S1 (20 DTUs). Is it possible that this simple query is being slowed down by my DTU limit?

Comment: Have you checked to make sure there is no deadlock?

Comment: Not formally but I am pretty sure there is not - I have turned off any updates so my query is the only thing which should be hitting the DB.

Comment: Q: So did you ever resolve your Azure performance problem?

Comment: @FoggyDay Not yet, I think I have narrowed it to be something to do with my understanding of DTUs but need to find time to investigate further. I can't understand how a simply count(id) can max out my quota so I must be missing something.

Comment: I have re-stated this question more clearly here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26073079/simple-select-countid-uses-100-of-azure-sql-dtus) without all the earlier noise now it has been narrowed down to DTUs.

Comment: The main answer is that DTU is a terrible metric because some queries are IO bound and others CPU bound, and DTU is some black box "blend" of both. Upgrade to a higher performance tier, but even then you may be throttled... Seems to be a design choice by MS - it's about small transactions, not aggregation or analytics.

Answer (score 13):

I realize this is old, but I had the same issue.  I had a table with **2.5 million rows** that I imported from an on-prem database into Azure SQL and ran at S3 level. `Select Count(0) from Table` resulted in a 5-7 minute execution time vs milliseconds on-premise.

In Azure, index and table scans seem to be penalized tremendously in performance, so adding a 'useless' `WHERE` to the query that forces it to perform an index seek on the clustered index helped.

In my case, this performed almost identical `Select count(0) from Table where id > 0` resulted in performance matching the on premise query.

Comment: WOW. This worked for me too. I have a rather complex query, which contains a subquery. When i add the "useless" where clause to the subquery it went from 22 seconds to 1 second on Azure and 600ms to 160ms locally. However, this is a query I have control over. My app also uses EF which causes me enough uncertainty to look into moving back to VM.

Comment: I have a count query that already uses non-clusetered index and it takes 20 sec to count 1m rows, tried your suggestion with adding dummy PK condition but to no luck...

Answer (score 3):

Suggestion: try `select count(*)` instead: it might actually improve the response time:

- http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/which-index-will-sql-server-use-to-count-all-rows/

Also, have you done an "explain plan"?

- http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2011/12/15/sql-azure-management-portal-tips-and-tricks-part-ii/
- http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1657.gaining-performance-insight-into-windows-azure-sql-database.aspx

============  UPDATE ============

Thank you for getting the statistics.

You're doing a full table scan of 2M rows - not good :(

POSSIBLE WORKAROUND: query system table `row_count` instead:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/arunrakwal/archive/2012/04/09/sql-azure-list-of-tables-with-record-count.aspx

```
select t.name ,s.row_count from sys.tables t
join sys.dm_db_partition_stats s
ON t.object_id = s.object_id
  and t.type_desc = 'USER_TABLE'
  and t.name not like '%dss%'
  and s.index_id = 1
```

Comment: The select count(*) has not helped - actually, after a long period I got "A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The semaphore timeout period has expired.)"

I will check your other points soon.

Comment: Have ammended my answer above after viewing also the plan - seems a clustered index scan is taking up all the time. Should this really take so long though for a simply select count(id)?

Comment: Thank you for getting the statistics.  You're doing a full table scan of 2M rows - that's bad.  POSSIBLE WORKAROUND: query system table "row_count" instead: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/arunrakwal/archive/2012/04/09/sql-azure-list-of-tables-with-record-count.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the response. The problem is, this is only a sample query - but what if I want to do something like "select count(id) from TABLE where column = 1" for example? It is still slow. Should such a simple query really be so slow? Is 2M rows really a lot for SQL Server such that it would take over 10 minutes?

Do I need to manually add new indexes? I thought part of the SQL Azure benefit was minimal management.

Comment: Should have also re-iterated -  This query runs in 4 seconds on my local machine! So does the index scan really explain this?

Comment: 1) Adding indexes will *NOT* help "count()".  2) Yes, the problem is clearly Azure.  But a) what exactly *IS* the problem with Azure? b) what can you do about it?  3) Your suggestion about maxing out DTU's is a good one.  Further reading: [Performance in the new Azure](http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/05/19/performance-in-the-new-azure-sql-database-service-tiers/).

Comment: @chrisb If `column` is indexed and highly selective the performance won't be slow. The `Database Engine Tuning Advisor` can suggest what indexes you need to improve performance of your queries

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos: there's no "where" clause - it's just counting all the rows in a table.  Q: Do you really think an index would help?  *MAIN QUESTION*: Do you have any ideas why Azure is so many orders of magnitude slower than ordinary MSSQL?  Q: Do you think DTUs might indeed be a factor?  Q: Any other suggestions for troubleshooting Azure?

Comment: You miss the point. Comparing queries with and without criteria is pointless, the first will use *no* indexes, the second *will* use indexes. The difference can be several orders of magnitude. Create a realistic query and worry only if *it* is slow. As for slower - DTU or IOPS means there is IO and CPU limiting while your desktop has full and dedicated access to a 6GB/s SATA. No problem with Azure, you bought a slow-IO instance for *this* kind of query.

Comment: No, you're missing the point.  I want to do a gosh darn "select count(*)", and I'd like for it to take closer to 5 seconds than 20 minutes.  It sounds like "Standard Azure SQL instance with performance level S1 (20 DTUs)" is the culprit.  Caveat emptor?

Comment: I've had similar issues on a very small 500 megabyte table - full scans on this table take milliseconds when running from a SQL Server VM locally, but in Azure on a 10 DTU instance, it takes minutes to do a simple SELECT max(column). The myth of "full table scans are bad" persists. If my workload is analysis & aggregation, SQL Azure significantly underperforms. It really seems it's designed for OLTP workloads that can be easily sharded.

Answer (score 3):

Quick refinement of @FoggyDay post.  If your tables are partitioned, you'll want to sum the rowcount.

```
SELECT t.name, SUM(s.row_count) row_count
FROM sys.tables t
JOIN sys.dm_db_partition_stats s
ON t.object_id = s.object_id
  AND t.type_desc = 'USER_TABLE'
  AND t.name not like '%dss%'
  AND s.index_id = 1
GROUP BY t.name
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but I found it while I was looking into a similar problem. If you just want to know the number of records on the table (which is what this looks like), then you could query SQL metadata as follows

```
SELECT row_count
FROM sys.dm_db_partition_stats
where object_id = object_id('[dbo].[mytable]') and index_id <= 1
```

I think this should give you the information you want but in a much more reasonable time and cost.